# How to reuse the view created previously when Fragment returns to the layout from back stack?

Tags: android, view, transactions, fragment

It's well known that the Fragment instance would not be destroyed when it is added to the back stack (see: [Creating a Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating)).

My fragment had a complex view. My intent was to prevent the view from being re-created when the fragment returned to the layout from back stack, in order to to render more quickly.

I had the codes in my class of Fragment extension similar as following:

```
View firstView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (firstView == null) {
        firstView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_view, container, false);
        Button btn_read = (Button)firstView.findViewById(R.id.btn_read);
        btn_read.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  // do something
            }
        });
    }

    return firstView;
}
```

And my Fragment was added to the back stack.

However, when I pop up the back stack by pressing 'back', I got the following exception. Obviously, the view created previously in the onCreateView was still attached to somewhere and it could not be reused for the new parent.

I understand that it's not wise to not following the 'general pattern' of using fragment. I'm just curious about how to prevent the BIG view from being re-created to increase the performance in Fragment.

------------- exception ---------------

```
03-25 23:55:38.354: W/dalvikvm(314): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
03-25 23:55:38.354: E/AndroidRuntime(314): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-25 23:55:38.445: E/AndroidRuntime(314): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
03-25 23:55:38.445: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1861)
03-25 23:55:38.445: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1756)
03-25 23:55:38.445: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1713)
03-25 23:55:38.445: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1693)
03-25 23:55:38.445: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout.wrap(NoSaveStateFrameLayout.java:40)
03-25 23:55:38.445: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:874)
03-25 23:55:38.445: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
03-25 23:55:38.445: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:697)
03-25 23:55:38.445: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1465)
03-25 23:55:38.445: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:447)
03-25 23:55:38.445: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:164)
03-25 23:55:38.445: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:1863)
03-25 23:55:38.445: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1061)
03-25 23:55:38.445: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2043)
03-25 23:55:38.445: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1631)
03-25 23:55:38.445: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2368)
03-25 23:55:38.445: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2338)
03-25 23:55:38.445: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1641)
03-25 23:55:38.445: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 23:55:38.445: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-25 23:55:38.445: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-25 23:55:38.445: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 23:55:38.445: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-25 23:55:38.445: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-25 23:55:38.445: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-25 23:55:38.445: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 23:55:38.445: I/Process(52): Sending signal. PID: 314 SIG: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
if (view != null) { 
   ((ViewGroup) view.getParent()).removeView(view);
} else {
   // Create your view
   ...
}

return view
```